# How to get JSON data from Odoo using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, getjson, odoo-8

I am trying to get data from Odoo (v8) database as JSON using Jquery Mobile App. Please give me an example to access Odoo DB and API using Jquery. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a controller for this, the code of should look something like this:

```
from openerp.addons.web import http

class MainController(http.Controller):
   @http.route('/jquery/json', type="json", auth="public")
   def json(self):
       return {
           'key': 'value',
           'items': range(1, 10)
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Yusnel Rojas Garcia. How can i trigger this controller from jquery side? i mean how can i display the datas from controller on my App? I am new to jquery.